# RSA Private Key Format Without Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: rsa

I've been implementing RSA as a learning exercise and am at a point now where I'd like to try serializing my key to a file using some standard format. I've implemented it without using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, so my private key is composed only of my modulus $n=pq$ and my modular inverse exponent $d$. I've seen that PKCS1 & PKCS8 expect the use of the Chinese Remainder theorem. I know that I could simply derive these values, but is there any standard format where I can encode only my $n$ and $d$ without deriving the values for CRT implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any standard format where I can encode only my n and d without deriving the values for CRT implementations?

Actually, for the standard [PKCS #1 private key format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-3.2), the CRT parameters are optional.  As you can read in the linked text, one of the options is that the private key just stores $n$ and $d$.

Comment: 3.2 defines abstract representation(s) not directly serializable; A.1.2 defines ASN.1 that is serializable and requires CRT (except the 'multi-prime' part is optional). OTOH [JOSE/JWK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518.html#section-6.3.2) makes the CRT fields 'should' -- recommended but not required. OpenPGP contains p,q but not dp,dq and pinv instead of qinv -- always. PKCS11 transfers each field separately on the API but the supported and required fields (beyond n,e,d) are up to the 'token' i.e. device or instance.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: I remember a version of the PKCS #1 private key format with only the n, e, d fields (just omitting the others).  However, all the references I now check have the CRT parameters mandatory...